# Leaflet with Customs Tiles seems to not be working

Tags: javascript, html, web, leaflet

I am trying to use Leaflet in Combination with Custom Tiles to make a fictional Map, but it seems to not be working even when I set the Error Tile URL to a completely different image, it doesn't even show that.

My JS Code looks like this:

```js
axios.get("https://crugg.de/udumap/map1/tiles/tiles.json").then((result) => {
    let tilesData = JSON.parse(result.data.replace(/(\/\/)[A-Z a-z,:'()\/.#0-9]*/gm, ""));
    console.log(tilesData.center);
    let map = L.map('map', {
        center: [tilesData.center[0], tilesData.center[1]],
        zoom: tilesData.center[2]
    }).setView([tilesData.center[0], tilesData.center[1]], tilesData.center[2]);
    L.tileLayer('https://crugg.de/udumap/map1/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">UD:RP Map</a> contributors',
        minZoom: tilesData.minzoom,
        maxZoom: tilesData.maxzoom,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        bounds: L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(tilesData.bounds[0], tilesData.bounds[1]), L.latLng(tilesData.bounds[2], tilesData.bounds[3])),
        errorTileUrl: "https://crugg.de/udumap/map1/tiles/17/107729/82841.png"
    }).addTo(map);
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5xprc6n3/1/
This is my first time using Leaflet and I have no Idea why this isn't working.

Comment: I think this is one more case of [confusing lat-long with long-lat](https://macwright.org/lonlat/). Double-check that the lat-lng coordinates of your fictional data are where you expect them to be (and remember that latitude cannot be outside the -90,90 range).

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `bounds` property.

```
L.tileLayer('https://crugg.de/udumap/map1/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">UD:RP Map</a> contributors',
        minZoom: tilesData.minzoom,
        maxZoom: tilesData.maxzoom,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        errorTileUrl: "https://crugg.de/udumap/map1/tiles/17/107729/82841.png"
    }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: But now the only thing I see is a split between the Error Tile and grey but my roads and everything are nowhere to be seen (even though they can clearly be seen in the tiles on my server)

Comment: look in the network analysis, it wants to take the tile like that: https://crugg.de/udumap/map1/tiles/12/3122/0.png but there is no tile on this path

Comment: Because Zoom 12 doesn't exist. I've set minZoom to 13... But even when I zoom in it still doesn't work